# VBA- Trouble with a ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1

Tags: excel, vba

Thank you for taking the time to help.  I have a macro that looks up a workbook.  From the recalled workbook, I want cell A1 in "Book1" to = cell A1 in the recalled workbook.  I then want to auto fill over to K1 and down to K20.  However, the range of data that I want to transfer isnt doing so.

My goal is to have the range on "book1" = the range on the recalled workbook- that way when another parties edits the recalled workbook, "book1" will reflect those edits.

I know PQ could be a good option for this but I want to try this avenue first.

My macro:

```vb
Sub copydata()

Dim path As String
path = InputBox("Please input path")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim actualfile As Workbook
Set actualfile = ActiveWorkbook

Dim script As Object
Set script = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim catalogue As Object
Set catalogue = script.GetFolder(path)

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False

Dim textfile As Object
For Each textfile In catalogue.Files

    Workbooks.Open textfile
    
    Dim loadedfile As Workbook
    Set loadedfile = ActiveWorkbook
    
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='loadedfile.Worksheets(1)'!RC"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:K1"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("A1:K1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:K20"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("A1:K20").Select

Next textfile

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True

End Sub
```

I tried setting "book1" as an active workbook and no success.

Edit:  Replying to some questions-------------------------------------------

There is a workbook containing this code. Then there is the ActiveWorbook actualfile. Are these two the same?

No they are different.  The macro linked is native to book1 (open through entire process)

What are the recalled workbook and Book1?

Excel workbooks

Where should these formulas refer to and where should they be written to i.e. there is no mention of the worksheets?

worksheet one for both workbooks

If you're writing to the same worksheet, then the only remaining references will be references to the last opened file.

I am writing to book1.  In other words I want to type "=" in A1 on book1, and then double click A1 on the recalled workbook and hit enter.  Then, on book1 cell A1, I want to remove $$ so i can autofill a range.  That way any edits from the recalled worksheet will be reflected on book1.

Also, you need to close the files. Please do clarify. You can edit your post at any time.

I am a newbie- thank you for taking the time to help me see these issues with my code

Comment: There is a workbook containing this code. Then there is the ActiveWorbook `actualfile`. Are these two the same? What are the *recalled workbook* and `Book1`? Where should these formulas refer to and where should they be written to i.e. there is no mention of the worksheets? If you're writing to the same worksheet, then the only remaining references will be references to the last opened file. Also, you need to close the files. Please do clarify. You can [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71700594/edit) at any time.

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help.  I added an edit that tries to answer the issues you pointed out.

Comment: After your clarifications, I understand that you have one (irrelevant) file with this code and the `Book1` file, both open. Your code is opening a bunch of other files. So if you create references in `[Book1]Sheet1!A1:K20` to the first file, where will you create the references to the other files?

Comment: For the other files, I am going to open a new tab.  To my understanding it should only be opening one file (the address I give it goes to one folder with only one excel file in it).  A bit more context, I am try to compile a "master" workbook that compiles references from 600+ workbooks that various users are editing daily.